# promise not resolving before return

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I am parsing through an array of files and posting to the database.  As part of that, I need to keep totals of the data in the files, and a count of successful record insertions into the database.  The promise is not waiting for all the records to be written to the database.

I am looking for the parserResults method to return the testResults back to the calling .reduce.  It does pass it back, but the insertSuccess = 0.

I put in some console logs to see what it is doing and the finalResult  is displaying on the console before the incremented insertSuccess counter is incremented.

Console.log results

```js
In parseresults ui-results-11705.json
In parseresults ui-results-14981.json
In parseresults ui-results-14982.json
In parseresults ui-results-28274.json
In parseresults ui-results-368.json

finalResult =  { insertSuccess: 0,
  insertFailed: 0,
  testPassedCount: 2,
  testFailedCount: 3 }

insertSuccess 1
insertSuccess 2
insertSuccess 3
insertSuccess 4
insertSuccess 5
```

This is the code calling the function that will parse the files

```js
 matches.reduce(function (p, val) {
    return p.then(function () {
      console.log('p', p);
      return parser.parseResults(val);
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function (finalResult) {
     console.log('finalResult = ', finalResult);
}, function (err) {
     console.log('error in reduce', err);
});
```

Here is the method being called

```js
protractorParser.prototype.parseResults = function (fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('In parseresults', fileName);
        var currentFile = './testing/results/' + fileName
        json.readFile(currentFile, function (err, obj) {
            if (err != null) {
                console.log('error reading file', err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(obj);
            }
        });
    }).then(function (obj) {
        var results = [];


        for (var suite in obj) {
            var specs = obj[suite].specs;
            for (let i = 0; i < specs.length; i++) {
                const assert = specs[i];
                const tcR = /TC[\d]+/;
                const tc = assert.description.match(tcR);

                let Passed = 1;
                let Message = '';
                let Stack = '';
                if (assert.failedExpectations.length) {
                    const expectation = assert.failedExpectations[assert.failedExpectations.length - 1];
                    Passed = 0;
                    Message = expectation.message;
                    Stack = expectation.stack.split('\n')[1].trim();
                    testResults.testFailedCount++
                } else {
                    testResults.testPassedCount++
                }
                if (tc != null) {

                    const time = moment().utcOffset(config.get('settings.timeOffset')).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
                    const promise = utility.TestDataManager.insertAutomationResults(tc[0], assert.description, Passed, process.env.testBuild, 'P', Message, Stack, 0, time, '');
                    results.push(promise.then(() => {

                        testResults.insertSuccess++;
                        console.log('insertSuccess', testResults.insertSuccess);

                    },
                        err => { console.log('… failed', err); throw err; }
                    ));

                } else {
                    console.log('no test case found for test: ' + assert.description + ' -- skipping');
                    // I don't think you want to `throw err` here, right?
                }
            }
        }
        return (Promise.all(results), testResults);
    });
};
```

I have played around with several different scenarios in the code and can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Christine

Comment: `reduce` isn't a promise aware function, ie it doesn't care what you are returning, it's just going to pass it through to the next iteration and not wait.

Comment: `return (Promise.all(results), testResults);` this returns `testResults` only (see [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)) - which isn't a promise, therefore the promises in `results.push(promise.then(() => {` are not waited for

Comment: @PatrickEvans - This looks like the proper way to use `.reduce()` to sequence a series of async operations that return a promise.  The problem seems to be that `parseResults()` doesn't return a promise because the `return` statement is messed up.

Comment: as `testResults` looks to be global - or at least in a higher (common) scope, no need to return it anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX - Perhaps they don't need to return `testResults`, but other code they are using wants it to be the `finalResult` of the `.reduce()` loop so  one could return it to make that happen.

Comment: @Jaromanda - But I need access to the counts in the testResults.  If I don't return it, then how do I use the counts?

Comment: I guess you don't need toe results of Promise.all - so jfriend's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: @jfriend00 - Do you know how I would write it to pass back the testResults

Comment: @ChristineEdwards -  I wrote an answer 8 minutes ago to show you how.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Sorry, I wrote my question before I saw your answer.  It is working great now.  Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseResults()` is not properly returning a promise, therefore your `p.then()` inside the `.reduce()` loop doesn't wait for anything.

Change this:

```
return (Promise.all(results), testResults);
```

to this:

```
return Promise.all(results).then(() => testResults);
```

The code you were using: `return (Promise.all(results), testResults);` was only returning `testResults`, not a promise.  What I think you want is to know when all the promises are done and then to make `testResults` be the resolved value.  To do that, you use `.then()` on the `Promise.all()` and then return `testResults` from that `.then()` handler.  That will return a single promise whose resolved value is `testResults`.

FYI, you may not need to do that at all because `testResults` appears to be a higher scoped variable that you could just refer to directly.  If you're willing to do that, then you would just change to:

```
return Promise.all(results);
```

And, then don't use `finalResult` in your final `.then()` handler, just refer to the higher scoped `testResults` variable directly.

---

FYI, a cleaner implementation of this could pass in an object that each iteration of the loop returns and passes on to the next iteration so there's no reference at all to a higher scoped variable and everything is more self contained.  Then, you would use the first type of return I showed you, but you'd return the passed in object, not the higher scoped object.

Comment: Thanks again.  Just checked it